# Python Socket Connect poloniex

Tags: python, sockets, poloniex

Hi I Want [Python Socket Connect Poloniex API](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker).

I ran the code. But I can not get the results I want.

I Made Code:

===================================================================

```
import requests
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("poloniex.com",443))

message="GET /public?command=returnTicker HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: poloniex.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1\r\n\r\n"

s.send(message)

print s.recv(5000)
```

===================================================================

Response Text:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> Server: cloudflare-nginx
>
> Date: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 02:52:22 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Content-Length: 275
>
> Connection: close CF-RAY: - 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

===================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is right - you're sending an HTTP request to port 443 which is the HTTPS port. If you want to send an HTTP request, use port 80. I have just tried to send a request to port 80, and the response says I should be using HTTPS from now on (see `Location: https://` part):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 13:40:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d28a8f446379618a093014a5f13bbcb141497966052; expires=Wed, 20-Jun-18 13:40:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.poloniex.com; HttpOnly
Location: https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 371f2473b09f5a7a-BOS
```

In this case you should use whether `ssl` module instead of `socket`, or just use `requests` since it is a simpler option.